# how to add right side menu in ios objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9.3

I want to add side menu on the right side in my project. I am present using SWRevealViewController third party classes in my project, in that revealToggle method is working fine for left menu but to add menu on the right side i used rightRevealToggle method which is not working fine. Any suggestion will help me to complete the task.

Comment: Please share your code here it will help to find solution to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use right side menu in Objective C the please use [MFSideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu)

In your AppDelegate:

**#import "MFSideMenu.h"**

```
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                containerWithCenterViewController:centerViewController
                                                leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                rightMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = container;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

#### Opening & Closing Menus

```
// toggle the right side menu
[self.menuContainerViewController toggleRightSideMenuCompletion:^{}];
// close the side menu
[self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed completion:^{}];
// open the right side menu
[self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateRightMenuOpen completion:^{}];
```

If you want to use [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) then can use the below code.

**Setting a right view controller:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *rightViewController;
Animated setting of the front view controller:

- (void)pushFrontViewController:(UIViewController *)frontViewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
Animating the position of the front view controller. Position can be: FrontViewPositionLeftSideMostRemoved, FrontViewPositionLeftSideMost, FrontViewPositionLeftSide, FrontViewPositionLeft, FrontViewPositionRight, FrontViewPositionRightMost or FrontViewPositionRightMostRemoved

- (void)setFrontViewPosition:(FrontViewPosition)frontViewPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
Creating and obtaining a pan gesture recognizer:

- (UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panGestureRecognizer;
Creating and obtaining a tap gesture recognizer:

- (UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapGestureRecognizer;
Other methods are documented in the SWRevealViewController.h header file.
```

Comment: thank you so much for the code it is working for me now. It was very helpful

Comment: My pleasure :) @CharishmaRao

Answer (score 0):

You are using SWRevealViewController, If you want to achieve menu on right side you just have to change the ViewControllers that you are passing to revealController

Example from SWRevealViewController

```
SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];
revealController.delegate = self;

revealController.rightViewController = YourViewController;
```

> Please look into AppDelegate.m of RevealControllerProject in the demo
>   project of SWRevealViewController.